# Need to locate XPath of email address

Tags: selenium, xpath

[image: need to find xpath of email address "indiart99@gmai.com",]

Its generated dynamically based on user login, Also the class="row-left" is used for 3 elements on the same page and XPath `//div[text()='~~' and @class = 'row-left']` is not locating the element.

Comment: Whether you want to get the Dynamic Email?

Comment: Result: Fail: Could not retrieve the value.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: share the html in text format instead of a image.

Comment: What do you want to do with the _Email Address_?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the required div element using child element as below and It will point the highlighted div.

```
//label[text()='Email Address']/parent::*
```

If you want to get the value of the dynamic email, you can get it as below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Email Address']/parent::*")).getText();
```

It will give the dynamic email ID